# URL is redirecting to another URL containing utm_source=404Redirect&utm_medium=404Redirect?

Tags: python, selenium, redirect, web-scraping, http-status-code-404

Anyone have any idea about redirected links that contain "utm_source=404Redirect&utm_medium=404Redirect" ?

Context:
I have collected multiple links from google news, in which one of the link is "https://techknowbits.com/2019/09/04/allogene-therapeutics-nasdaqallo-earns-hold-rating-from-jpmorgan-chase-co.html" when i am trying to open the link in browser either through selenium driver or normal browser it is redirecting me to "https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/ALLO/?**utm_source=404Redirect&utm_medium=404Redirect**".

my question here is:

Is it redirecting normally ? or

is it redirecting when there is a 404 error in the website ?

I am asking this question, because multiple other links

"https://technewsobserver.com/news/2019/09/14/0-54-eps-expected-for-allogene-therapeutics-inc-nasdaqallo-this-quarter.html",

"https://sundanceherald.com/2019/08/30/analysts-expect-allogene-therapeutics-inc-nasdaqallo-will-post-earnings-of-0-54-per-share.html",

"https://slatersentinel.com/news/2019/09/13/comparing-allogene-therapeutics-nasdaqallo-erytech-pharma-nasdaqeryp.html" are also redirecting me to that very page.

If 404 is the cause of redirection , then i should start handling that error otherwise i might end up collecting the same data for every 404 error

Answer (score 0):

[utm_* parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters) are from (always?) Google Analytics.
Are you getting a 404 when requesting those urls or it's just that you see 404 in the url?

Comment: I am not getting any 404 error its just redirecting me to that page, i am asking since the link is mentioning 404 re-direct

Comment: https://techknowbits.com/2019/09/04/allogene-therapeutics-nasdaqallo-earns-hold-rating-from-jpmorgan-chase-co.html returns a 301 redirect to 'https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/ALLO/?utm_source=404Redirect&utm_medium=404Redirect' returns a 200 ok. The parameters are there (I guess) just for google analytics. I don't think there's an error there.

Answer (score 0):

### UTM parameters

[Urchin Tracking Module (UTM) parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters) are different variants of URL parameters used to track the effectiveness of online marketing campaigns across traffic sources and publishing medias which was introduced by [Urchin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urchin_(software)) and are now supported out-of-the-box by [Google Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics). UTM parameters within the URL identifies the campaign that refers traffic to a specific website and attributes it to the browser's website session and the sessions after that until the campaign attribution window expires. The collected UTM parameters can be parsed by analytical tools and used to generate necessary reports.

As an example, in the following example url:

```
https://www.example.com/page?utm_content=buffercf3b2&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer
```

The UTM parameters are:

```
utm_content=buffercf3b2&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer
```

In your usecase:

- URL:

  ```
  https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/ALLO/?utm_source=404Redirect&utm_medium=404Redirect
  ```
- UTM parameters:

  ```
  utm_source=404Redirect&utm_medium=404Redirect
  ```

---

### UTM parameters

There are five UTM parameters and they can be used in any order:

```
Parameter    Purpose                                                        Examples
---------    -------                                                        --------
utm_source   Identifies which site sent the traffic.                        utm_source=Facebook
utm_medium   Identifies what type of link was used.                         utm_medium=cpc
utm_campaign Identifies a specific product promotion.                       utm_campaign=new_sale
utm_term     Identifies search terms.                                       utm_term=treck+shoes
utm_content  Identifies what was clicked to bring the user to the site.     utm_content=loginlink
```